# Three.js: How to add a skeleton as a child of another skeleton?

Tags: three.js

I have to skeletons s1 and s2, each of them has its own bone array, SkinnedMesh, and animation.

I'd like to know if it's possible to make s2 a sub skeleton of s1. i.e. set the root(b2) bone of s2 as a child of some bone (b1) in s1.

I tryed `b1.add(b2);` but seems like matrix of s2 is not updated as s1 moves.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `buildNodeHierarchy` in `GLTFLoader` at the end remove the added children and become a child of the scene root node.